# Why None Static Method dose not known as webmethod in AJax Call?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, xmlhttprequest, webmethod

in jQuery ajax or node.js or xmlhttprequest  I've see none static method doesn't  work for web method

Dose not Wrok

```
[WebMethod]
public string Method1()
{

    return values;
}
```

and this Work Correctly

```
[WebMethod]
public static string Method1()
{

    return values;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the method is accessed from an ajax call and not a full postback, there is no postback data ASP.NET would need to create and initialize an instance of the page. Thus the method must be static, so it can be called without instantiating the page.

Comment: that's mean  static method not initialize new instance of web page class then ajax call can be see this method ?

Comment: yes, to call the static method there is no need to instantiate a Page object, so the static method can be called with an ajax call